# UIPrintInteractionController presentFromRect issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, airprint

Im showing the AirPrint options from a UIButton using the presentFromRect method, everything is working as expected, but if i keep pressing the button fast enough my app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS, probably because of the popover not being release.

Im using Xcode 4.2 with ARC enabled.

Any help would be great!

**Update 2: The problem only occur on iOS 5 simulator, iPad 4.3 simulator works as expected.**

Update:

Here is the real problem:

* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible.'

Here is the code:

Here I'm calling my method:

```c
PrintUtils* printUtils = [[PrintUtils alloc] init];
printUtils.delegate = self;
[printUtils setHeader:@"Header"];
[printUtils print:self.webView fromRect:self.myButton.frame inView:self.menuView];
```

My method:

```c
- (void)print:(UIWebView *)webView fromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view
{

    printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    [printController setDelegate:self];


    if(!printController){

        NSError* error = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"Print unavailable!" code:0 userInfo:nil];

        [self showError:error];
        return;
    }

    UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler = 
    ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if(!completed && error){
            [self showError:error];
        }
    };

    UIPrintInfo* printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    [printInfo setJobName:header];
    [printInfo setDuplex:UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge];
    [printInfo setOutputType:UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral];

    UIPrintFormatter* viewFormatter = [webView viewPrintFormatter];

    CustomPrintPageRenderer *pageRenderer = [[CustomPrintPageRenderer alloc] init];    
    [pageRenderer setJobTitle:[printInfo jobName]];

    UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:HEADER_FOOTER_TEXT_HEIGHT]; 
    CGSize titleSize = [pageRenderer.jobTitle sizeWithFont:font];
    pageRenderer.headerHeight = pageRenderer.footerHeight = titleSize.height + HEADER_FOOTER_MARGIN_PADDING;


    [pageRenderer addPrintFormatter:viewFormatter startingAtPageAtIndex:0];

    [printController setPrintPageRenderer:pageRenderer];
    [printController setPrintInfo:printInfo];    
    [printController setPrintFormatter:viewFormatter];
    [printController setShowsPageRange:YES];    
    [printController presentFromRect:rect inView:view animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

}
```

My attempt to fix the problem implementing the UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate Method:

```c
- (void)printInteractionControllerWillPresentPrinterOptions:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController
{

    if (visible) {
        [printController dismissAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you ever figure this out? The problem is that you´re not checking if the device is an iPad or iPhone. iPhone does not support presentFromRect: but iPad does. That's why you get the bad access when you run it on iPhone.

Here's what you need to do:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

    [printController presentFromFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

} else {

    [printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

}
```

Comment: The use of presentFromFromBarButtonItem:animated:completionHandler: there was probably incidental- the same conditional code can be used for that call or the original  presentFromRect:inView:animated:completionHandler call.