# Phonegap printer plugin point at button clicked to open

Tags: javascript, cordova, printing, viewmodel

I have started using the [printer plugin by katzer](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer) but when calling the basic print function with just one parameter (HTML string), the box hovers in the middle of the screen. How can I get it to point at the button I have clicked to open it in JavaScript?

Image below shows what I need, the arrow pointing to a button

[image]

```
printdoc:function(e)
{
        var page = document.body.innerHTML;

    // Pass the HTML
    window.plugin.printer.print(page);
}
```

Example with another parameter

```
window.plugin.printer.print(page, { appId: 'epson.print' });
```

My button in HTML

```
<a id="printbtn" data-role="button" data-bind="click:printdoc">
```

Thank you

Comment: can you add some code to your question?

Comment: Done. I just want to know what parameter should go in the second parameter for the print function. I think this might point it at a button I have

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking. Are you asking how to call this function from clicking a button?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon no I'm asking how I can get the print box, once it's open, to point at the button

Comment: @DawsonLoudon I've added a photo to the post

Comment: Ok, I understand now. You would need to modify the native iOS code to do this. Are you familiar with this? If so, I can find an example.

Comment: I've done a little objective c. It would be useful if you could take a quick look in Katzers native code and tell me what to put where. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Ok, from looking over the code and reading the documentation from Apple, this is not possible on an iPhone. You would need to use `presentFromRect` instead of `presentAnimated` and `presentFromRect` is only available on the iPad. This is an Apple standard imposed by the SDK.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I was using it on iPad, so it's possible? If so, what do I have to do?

Comment: I'll add an answer below with some references and an example

Comment: @DawsonLoudon I see the function openPrintController in Katzers code with presentAnimated :YES. What so I do there?

Answer (score 1):

To add the pointer (arrow) to the top of the modal you will need to change the presentation from `presentAnimated:` to `presentFromRect:`.

On line 164 in `APPPrinter.m` you will change:

```
[controller presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:NULL];
```

to

```
[controller presentFromRect:CGRectMake(850, 0, 220, 60) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Note: the coords in the rect are an example, you will need to modify them to fit your application. Also, `inView:self.view` may need to be changed but I am not 100% what it should be.

You can also reference this post: [UIPrintInteractionController presentFromRect issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025399/uiprintinteractioncontroller-presentfromrect-issue)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll give it a try tomorrow and let you know what happens. Thank you again